# LayerNorm and Magnitude of Input

Tags: neural-networks

In LayerNorm, for a given layer, we first compute the mean and variance of the activation of each sample and then use them to normalize the said activation.

Specifically, the LayerNorm formula looks like this (from [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LayerNorm.html)):
$$
y = \frac{x-E[x]}{\sqrt{var(x) + \epsilon}}\times \gamma  + \beta
$$

If $\epsilon$ is small, then $y = LN(cx)$ for any $c>0$.

It appears that the information about magnitude $\|x\|$ is lost in the process. This feels like a problem in situations like an auto-encoder.

Comment: Not lost, but transformed (or mapped). The information is used to approximate a function that is used to map layer inputs to layer outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you elaborate why LayerNorm does not satisfy $f(cx)=f(x)$, where $f(.)$ is LayerNorm, $x$ is an input as a vector of features for a sample, and $c$ is a positive constant. It feels like standardization across the features of a single sample.